# Reverse (kbd) function?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I was wondering if there is a reverse `(kbd)` function, one I could use to get from a keycode a meaningful description of it, e.g., `C-b` from `2`.

Usually `(format "%c" x)` does work, but not for the previous example as well as for many others, as keybindings, specially on Emacs, are often more complicated than a single character, and even when they are indeed a single character, they can be a whitespace or a Tab.

It seems that the documentation functions use themselves the function `(describe-buffer-bindings)`, which is written in C and therefore immutable, and I'd like to avoid that route, if possible, and manipulate the data in my way to provide fancier features.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're probably looking for `(key-description KEYS &optional PREFIX)`.

For example: `(key-description [2])` and `(key-description (kbd "C-b"))` evaluate to `"C-b"`.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed! (key-description (format "%c" 2)) now returns C-b!

Comment: @konr I guess you should use `(vector 2)`, since some keymaps are really large integers where no character corresponds to them.

Answer (score 3):

Definition of inverse of kbd

```
(defun my-kbd-inverse (key)
  (if (numberp key)
      (setq key (vector key)))
  (key-description key))
```

Test

```
(defvar my-example-keys nil)
(setq my-example-keys
      (list 2 3 ?a
            24
            [?\C-x ?l]
            (list "C-x" "A")
            [(meta right) (meta left)]
            (kbd "<f9>")
            (kbd "<C-f9>")
            (kbd "C-M-a")
            [24 f9 97]))
(cl-loop for key in my-example-keys
         do
         (princ (my-kbd-inverse key))
         (terpri))
```

If there is any key that can be passed to `global-set-key` but doesn't work with the current definition of `my-kbd-inverse`, let me know.

Side note: there is a reason key-description doesn't take a character as argument. There are two gotchas of characters:

1. a character is simply a number. There is no separate data type for characters.
2. there is a sense that a character is *not* a key. A character is an input event. A sequence of input events form a key sequence (a keyboard shortcut) and a key sequence is called a key, in short. The character `?a` is not a key, but the vector `[a]` and the string "a" are. The functions `global-set-key`  and `key-description` only take keys.